# What happened to my kumquat tree?

Tags: fruit-trees

My kumquat tree began producing fruit this year that seems to be part lemon and part orange.  Always just good kumquats before now.  We do have both the lemon tree and orange trees nearby.

How does this happen?

Comment: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index;_ylt=Awr9BN8wyPxb.6sAOwlXNyoA;_ylu=X3oDMTByNWU4cGh1BGNvbG8DZ3ExBHBvcwMxBHZ0aWQDBHNlYwNzYw--?qid=20091207202447AALYKSu

Comment: This will help to explain hybridization of plants that able to hybridize. Also; https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index;_ylt=Awr9BN8wyPxb.6sAOwlXNyoA;_ylu=X3oDMTByNWU4cGh1BGNvbG8DZ3ExBHBvcwMxBHZ0aWQDBHNlYwNzYw--?qid=20091207202447AALYKSu